# Getting the CRC checksum of a byte array and adding it to that byte array

Tags: java, checksum, crc, modbus

I have this byte array:

```
static byte[] buf = new byte[] { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01,(byte)0x00, (byte) 0x01};
```

Now, the CRC checksum of this byte array is supposed to be 0x60, 0x0A. I want the Java code to recreate this checksum, however I cant seem to recreate it. I have tried crc16:

```
static int crc16(final byte[] buffer) {
    int crc = 0xFFFF;

    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length ; j++) {
        crc = ((crc  >>> 8) | (crc  << 8) )& 0xffff;
        crc ^= (buffer[j] & 0xff);//byte to int, trunc sign
        crc ^= ((crc & 0xff) >> 4);
        crc ^= (crc << 12) & 0xffff;
        crc ^= ((crc & 0xFF) << 5) & 0xffff;
    }
    crc &= 0xffff;
    return crc;

}
```

and convert them using Integer.toHexString(), but none of the results match the correct CRC. Could someone please point me in the right direction in terms of CRC formula.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

```
// Compute the MODBUS RTU CRC
private static int ModRTU_CRC(byte[] buf, int len)
{
  int crc = 0xFFFF;

  for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
    crc ^= (int)buf[pos] & 0xFF;   // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc

    for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {    // Loop over each bit
      if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {      // If the LSB is set
        crc >>= 1;                    // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
        crc ^= 0xA001;
      }
      else                            // Else LSB is not set
        crc >>= 1;                    // Just shift right
    }
  }
// Note, this number has low and high bytes swapped, so use it accordingly (or swap bytes)
return crc;  
}
```

You may have to reverse your return CRC to get the right endianness, though.  I even tested it here:

http://ideone.com/PrBXVh

Using windows calculator or something you can see that the first result (from the above function call) gives the expected value (albeit reversed).

Answer (score 4):

Would CRC32 do, or does it have to be CRC16?  If 32 is okay, have you tried using the `CRC32` in `java.util.zip`?

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

byte[] buf = new byte[] { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01,(byte)0x00, (byte) 0x01};
CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
crc32.update(buf);
System.out.printf("%X\n", crc32.getValue());
```

The output is:

```
F9DB8E67
```

Then you can do whatever additional calculation you want on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on modbus using Java 1.6, tried the above code and it only partially worked?  Agreed on some CRCs, wrong on others.  I researched it a bit more, and saw I had a problem with sign extension.  I masked off the high bits (see FIX HERE below) and now it works great.
NOTE:  All CRC calcs are not the same, MODBUS is a bit different:

```
    public static int getCRC(byte[] buf, int len ) {
    int crc =  0xFFFF;
    int val = 0;

      for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
        crc ^= (int)(0x00ff & buf[pos]);  // FIX HERE -- XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc

        for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {    // Loop over each bit
          if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {      // If the LSB is set
            crc >>= 1;                    // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
            crc ^= 0xA001;
          }
          else                            // Else LSB is not set
            crc >>= 1;                    // Just shift right
        }
      }
    // Note, crc has low and high bytes swapped, so use it accordingly (or swap bytes)
    val =  (crc & 0xff) << 8;
    val =  val + ((crc >> 8) & 0xff);
    System.out.printf("Calculated a CRC of 0x%x, swapped: 0x%x\n", crc, val);
    return val;  

}   // end GetCRC
```